# Missing api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1.dll

Tags: windows-7, windows

Im trying to start a program in steam its called Youtube VR and it wont launch. every time I launch the program it says that Im missing a dll called api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1 its a system error I dont know how to get it either. I read that the program is suppost to already have it in its install folder but for some reason its not using it. I know that those dll downloader websites are all sketchy so thats out of the option. if you could help me fix this problem that would be cool. OS Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1124827/missing-api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0-dll?rq=1 and https://superuser.com/questions/986496/missing-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-1-1-0-dll?rq=1 and https://superuser.com/questions/1224991/how-to-install-the-dll-files-in-windows-7/1224996#1224996 and https://superuser.com/questions/393878/api-ms-win-core-registry-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1281365/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-fro)

Answer (score 1):

> Im trying to start a program in steam its called Youtube VR and it wont launch. every time I launch the program it says that Im missing a dll called api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-1 its a system error I dont know how to get it either.

YouTube VR appears to be Universal Windows Platform application or at least requires the UWP API.  If it is a UWP application it means it can only run on Windows 10.  The minimum specifications for the program in question confirms this fact.  You will be unable to run this particular application unless you upgrade to Windows 10.

[image]

- [Source](http://store.steampowered.com/app/755770/YouTube_VR/)
- [API Sets for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt186421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If the problem is simply cause by a missing requirement, it appears you need to install [Update for Universal C Runtime in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows) but I have my doubts since Steam would have installed it if it was required for the application in question.